# Leaking the local class outside function

Tags: c++, local-class

I have a function named `return_local` where it returns an instance of a local class enclosed with a lambda.

```cpp
auto return_local() {
  return [] {
    static int sample { 5 };
    struct Point {
      int x, y;
      int show_sample() { return sample; }
    };
    return Point {};
  }();
}
```

```cpp
using Point = decltype(return_local());
```

Now, I can use `Point` as alias with characteristics of local classes.

```cpp
Point p {.x = 4, .y = 1};
p.show_sample(); // returns 5
```

Is this code normal? Are there any benefits of using this "leaked" class?

Comment: You can do that, but it's not clear why you would want to. Why not just define `Point` at namespace scope?

Comment: It's a bit unusual, but the code is within the bounds of what I'd consider normal.  I don't see any benefits to coding this way over declaring Point on its own and having the sample be a class static variable.  The downside, as I see it, is it is more cognitive load for maintenance.

Comment: This is sometimes called a "Voldemort Type" (A type that shall not be named).